# how can I connect godaddy domain with a Wordpress site on google cloud?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I make a wordpress site on google cloud but don't know how to connect it with domain name in godaddy.com. There is option to transfer domain name to url but it gives 301 or 302 error while sitemap on google search engine. So, how i get out of it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a DNS `A` record for your domain, pointing to the IP address of your system on Google Cloud.
2. There is no step 2.